# Connect via Socket from Host machine to container using host:port (port mapping) (windows to windows)

Tags: windows, docker, sockets, dockerfile

Connect to docker container (windows 10) from host via Socket connection

I have tried to build an image using windows 10 as base image, expose port that i want connect to from host machine (40030).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 40020
```

And this is the docker run command:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 40020:40020 sample:dev
```

I expect to connect from Host machine to container machine via socket connection. Maybe there are some issue with Socket connection at all, because simple HTTP server is working (simple nodejs server return the response from container to host)

Comment: The simple HTTP server that is working, is it also working in a container or on the host directly?

Comment: Yes, i can access the server inside of container from the container and from the host